# Is .parents returning array of jQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is easy, I've created one line of script, for select element and his parents with some class. It look like this:

```
clicked = $('.clicked');
objects = jQuery.merge( [clicked], clicked.parents('.parent') );
```

When I do `console.log(objects)` the result in Firebug is

```
[Object[li.clicked], li.parent, li.parent, li.parent]
```

As I can see, parents return only a DOM element, not a jQuery object. How can I create jQuery object from this element?

Or another question, let's say I have another object $(li.parent), how can I found if this new parent is already in array objects? I've tried to do `jQuery.inArray( $(li.parent), objects )` but it always return -1, because obviously

> Object[li.parent] != li.parent

Can someone help me?

Comment: `.parents` behaves exactly like any other jquery method that selects elements.

Comment: Hum.. I wonder How much parents can an element have? 10, 20, maybe 10 000?

Comment: This might help http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: You are `merge`ing an array that contains a jQuery collection with a pure jQuery collection. What output did you expect?